# When it's better choose an specific Dx than calculate the Derivative?

Tags: analysis, physics, kinematics

I was thinking about this problem: a car that moves as x(t) = t^3 in t=0 if i calculate the derivative in that point is 0. But in the reality the car near the time 0 its accelerating.
If i choose certain dt like 0,01 and i solve ((t + dt)^3 - t^3)/dt when t=0, the rate of change it's 0,001. Little but not cero. Therefore Can i say its a better aproximation than the derivative? It exits some  clue about when its better choose a specific dt than make dt aproaches to 0 (derivative)?

Comment: “Better” in what sense? The velocity at $t=0$ *is* zero.

Comment: No. U can have a velocity if you dont have Δt. Think.

Answer (score 1):

The *velocity* at $t=0$ is indeed zero. What you've calculated is the *average velocity* between $t=0$ and $t=0.01$, which is a different, albeit useful, value. In general, average velocity & instantaneous velocity (i.e. the usual velocity) are equal in case of constant-speed motion, which will have an equation of the form $x(t)=at+b$ (here, both velocities will be equal to $a$).

Comment: The problem is that to calculate velocity some amount of time must pass. Because of the definition of velocity, instantaneous velocity is an oximoron. It feels weird, isnt it? In this sense, the derivative isnt exactly velocity but a constant aproximation, then maybe i want a Dx that aproximates some velocity to tell me another thing about the movement. This is some cool video that inspired this question: https://youtu.be/9vKqVkMQHKk

Comment: U can have a velocity if you dont have Δt. Think.